# Ability to Map to separate Task ARNs in Step Functions?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I'd like to be able to use Step Functions to dynamically map to multiple different tasks based on an input list containing the resource ARNs of the tasks to map to.

Ideally the input would look something like:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "arn": "ARN_1", "some_other_input": "blah" },
    { "arn": "ARN_2", "something_else": "doop" }
  ]
}
```

And the Map state (or anything else that would allow this) would call each task specified by the "arn" key and pass it the rest of the inputs.

I've attempted to use `"$$.Map.Item.Value.arn"` as the Task resource, but it complains that `Value is not a valid resource ARN`

Based on the documentation for [Context Object Data For Map States](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map), it seems that this is not possible, as they state that `You must define parameters from the context object in the "Parameters" block of the main Map state, not within the states included in the "Iterator" section.`

Is there a good way to work around this?

*Edit*: Should also mention that these tasks would be somewhat long-running and I need the outputs to be returned to the step function once they've all completed.